# Como puedo definir una función que haga que busque lo que quiero al escribir en un Entry y darle al Botón?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

**La idea es que cuando escriba algo en el Entry(my_entry) y pulse el Botón(search_button) me diga si esta en la Listbox ya sea con un messagebox o con un print por ejemplo.**

***Imagen de ejemplo:***

***[image: Imagen de ejemplo]***

***Codigo de ejemplo:***

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Example")
root.geometry("140x250+300+300")
root.config(bg = "Gray")

def add(name):
    listbox.insert(END,(name))
    my_entry.delete(0,END)

name = StringVar()


listbox = Listbox(root, fg= "White", bg= "Black")
listbox.grid(padx = 5,pady = 5,columnspan=2)

my_entry = Entry(root, textvariable= name)
my_entry.grid(padx = 5,pady = 5,columnspan=2)

add_button = Button(root, text= "Add", command= lambda: add(name.get()))
add_button.grid(row=3,column=0,padx = 5,pady = 5)

search_button = Button(root, text= "Search")
search_button.grid(row=3,column=1,padx = 5,pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Y que has intentado hasta ahora para lograr tu objetivo? No vamos a hacer el código por ti. Si no sabes como empezar, te recomiendo aprender más sobre el Listbox y en base a los nuevos conocimientos avanzar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `listbox.get(0, END)` obtienes en una tupla todos los datos guardados en el listbox, y con `in`, simplemente consultas si el valor del Entry está dentro de esa tupla.

```
def search(name):
    print(name in listbox.get(0, END))

search_button = Button(root, text="Search", command=lambda: search(name.get()))
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, lo probé y funciona, gracias por aclararme ya que utilizaba ese mismo código pero sin el `.get`

Comment: @Quro De nada, si la respuesta te ha ayudado y resuelve el problema podrías marcarla como aceptada :)